# svg triangle with 100% width

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to use an svg image in 100% width which has as filled background from the top left to the bottom right. I've tried several ways to make it always 100% wide (background-size, etc.) but it doesn't work.

If I'm opening the svg source code, there are several "fix" widths. Maybe this is the problem. But I don't know how I could fix it.

It would be great if I could place this swg as a background of a div. (using css)

Here is my svg Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="1280px" height="70px" viewBox="0 0 1280 70" enable-background="new 0 0 1280 70" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon points="1280,70 0,70 0,0 "/>
</svg>
```

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this? I also thought about another way, with an rotated div container. But I think svg is the best way.

Here you can see an example:

[jsfiddle.net/maszzfom](http://jsfiddle.net/maszzfom)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove width and height

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1280 70" enable-background="new 0 0 1280 70" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<polygon points="1280,70 0,70 0,0 "/>
</svg>
```

css

```
svg{width:100%}
```

[resource on responsive svg](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0ae1ztq2/)

upate: save the svg as file and use it like this

```
.element {
    background-image: url(image.svg);
    /* other styles */
}
```

If you want a pure css solute the give [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) or [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) a try

Comment: Is it also possible to do this with CSS? I would like to use a div and place the background with "background-image: url()" Thansk for your quick response.

Comment: Yes but you will the have to save it as `.svg`file  read this please  http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/19/making-svgs-responsive-with-css/

Comment: The solution with "background-image: url()" doesn't work, because the .element needs a defined height. In my case this is 70px, and then it is not working as expected. The image is only 1280px wide. and repeated then.

Comment: can i see your css ? are you using `background-size:cover` or `background-size:contain`?

Comment: ok you are using it as "data:image/svg+xml" and not as local file please use `image.svg`

Comment: I've just done this for the jsfiddle example. I'm using it as an local file and have the same problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61284/discussion-between-emjay-and-tambo).

Comment: To ensure that the triangle is always 100% of the width, you may also have to add the attribute `preserveAspectRatio="none"` to your `<svg>`.  Otherwise if the container height drops below 70, the triangle will shrink and become narrower.

Answer (score 5):

If the triangle doesn't have content by itself (just decoration), it should be defined in the CSS.

Following your example with a triangle ( 100% width and static height 70px), you could achieve it as:

```css
.triangle {

  position: relative;

}

.triangle:before {

  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  background-size: 100% 100%;

  content: '';

  display: block;

  position: absolute;

  width: 100%;

  left: 0;

  bottom: -70px;

  height: 70px;

  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100' height='100' viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio='none'%3E%3Cpolygon points='100,0 100,100 0,100' style='fill:%23000000;' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");

}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

- The triangle coordinates are possible to invert: points='0,0 0,100 100,100'
- You could change the triangle color: "fill:%23000000;"
- The CSS works with :before and :after, depending your needs!
- Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b8czxyzg/